# Is there any option to monitor bluetooth packet data on Android 4.0.4?

Tags: android, bluetooth, augmented-reality, packet

I am working on a project to analyse the packet loss in bluetooth transfer between Android 4.4 device and android 4.0.4(EPSON Augmented Reality Glass Moverio- BT200.

I got the packet list in Android 4.4 device. Is there any possible way to monitor the packets in Android 4.0.4 in developer option?